# I do get a result from the back but can't assign it to a variable

Tags: reactjs

i use axios to retrieve data from back.
I do get a result from the back. I can even console.log it. Yet, even I assign it to the *recipe* variable. It doesn't works. I get a empty array.
Anyone would known why ? I really don't understand.

FRONT

```
import React, { useEffect,useState } from 'react'
import Header from '../../components/Header'
import axios from 'axios'

export default function OneRecipePage(props) {

    const [recipe, setrecipe] = useState([])

    useEffect(() => {
        const id = props.match.params.id
        const getRecipe = async () => {
            const url = `http://localhost:8000/user/recipe/${id}`
            const result = await axios.get(url)
            setrecipe(result.data)
            console.log('recipe',recipe)
            console.log('from back', result.data);
        }
        getRecipe()
    },[])

    return (
        <div>
            <Header/>
            <main class="main">
                <div class="heading">
                    <aside class="recipes-info__category_name">{recipe.name}
                    </aside>
                    <aside class="recipes-info__date">{recipe.created_at}
                    </aside>
                    <h2 class="heading-secondary heading-secondary--big">{recipe.title}</h2>
                    <p>by author</p>
                </div>

                <div class="image-box">
                    <img class="image" src={recipe.photo}/>
                </div>

                <div class="recipes-details"></div>

            </main>
            
        </div>
    )
}
```

BACK

```
router.get('/recipe/:id', (req,res) => {
    const id = req.params.id
    connection.query('SELECT * from ETB.recipes WHERE id = ?', id, (err, results) => {
        if (err) {
            res.status(500).send('Error retrieving the recipe')
        }else {
            res.status(200).json(results)
        }
    })
})
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In react, set State is an asynchronous aciton. By the time it executes next line, it is no guaranteed that it has set state.

instread of this

```
`setrecipe(result.data)
 console.log('recipe',recipe)`
```

you can use `useEffect()` to detect the change in state.

`useEffect(()=>console.log('recipe',recipe),[recipe])`